# When to Use Imperfective or Perfective Imperative.. if at all?

Tags: грамматика, перевод

I am having a difficult time determining when to use the imperative mood and what the difference between imperfective and perfective is...
The verb "to die" is a difficult one because is it a verb that WILL be completed? Of course it is a fact.. no one has the option to avoid it. However how does this work?

There is a show called LOST where they use the quote "live together, die alone." When they debate saving someone or doing something dangerous, they say, "live together, die alone." as a phrase to live by... How do you translate this? I am getting a tattoo with half English half Russian so "live together (English), die alone (Russian)..." Would I use imperative mood imperfective умира́йте, or imperative perfective **умри́те**?? Would I use **умирать/умереть** ? Would I use the we conjugation as in "we live together, we die alone" **умира́ем**?? "**___ в одиночестве**" what verb tense do I use and why?? I've done so much research but can't figure out which is best.. It is a quote to live by. When I am with my friends and they ask if I can drive half way across the country to help them with something important, I would respond "live together, die alone" meaning I will do it because we have to stick together while we're on this Earth.. but at the end of the day when we die we will be alone.

Answer (score 1):

Look, I think [this](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%BC_%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5,_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5) is the official translation:

> Живем вместе, умираем поодиночке

This is interesting because they are using the present tense. To be honest, I don't feel the imperative will sound good here. For me, this phrase should not have such a mood. It's like a life credo.

Comment: I agree that the imperative is misleading, even in the original English phrase. I didn't get it the first time around. If it was down to me, I would put it this way: "Together we live, alone we die." But then, an idiom is an idiom...